# SSH to raspberry pi over internet

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I want to ssh to my Raspberry pi that will be on a different network from my home network. ON my home network router, I set up port forwarding: Set the WAN and LAN start and end ports to 22, set the protocol to TCP. The WAN Host IP address (start & end) set to 192.168.x.x (it is going to be static so i set the same start/end address), and the LAN host IP address to my static IP inside my home network. Now, from inside my home network, how do I ssh to the rpi? Is it >>> ssh username@public_ip_address?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up SSH over internet on my Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13861/setting-up-ssh-over-internet-on-my-pi)

Comment: As far as I understand you want to connect to your RasPi on the internet from a device on your local network. Does the RasPi have a public ip address? Can you ping it from the local device? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the author didn't provide any clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `0.0.0.0` for translate an unknown IP address (because it can be dynamic). Redirect all TCP input traffic from all IP addr port `22` to your host to destination `192.168.0.2` (from my example) and port `22` (change this port for prevent mass scanning)

[image]
Where `92.x.x.x.x` is **PUBLIC IP** and `192.168.0.2` is **PRIVATE IP**.

then use :

```
ssh -p 22 pi@92.x.x.x.x
```

You must test this configuration from a device behind the N.A.T router. But you can access to your local SSH server with:

```
ssh -p 22 pi@192.168.0.2
```

from a device that is on the same network as your `192.168.X.X/X` network.

Note: example for IPv4 only.